# Old Site URLS are marked as Duplicates after Site Migration

Tags: duplicate-content, xml-sitemap, migration

site migration gone wrong- > https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq3IO.jpg

3 weeks After a failed site migration and 95% of my traffic gone (see screenshot), I decided to remove the redirect from the old sitemap, so that google can discover the redirects for each old URL one by one.

I assume that, without removing the redirect for the old site map URL to the new sitemap without being able to discover the redirects appropriately. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Before I did this the old URLs all had the "Page with redirect" status. The day after i removed the redirect and resubmitted the old sitemap all my old URLs are now tagged with "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical"-, while referencing the new domain url.

This can be good or bad. Why have all my old urls been taged as "duplicates". What should i do now?

Comment: You would expect your old URLs to be marked as duplicate. That means the Google has found the redirect and is treating the new URL  the same as the old URL.

Comment: Would i not expect the "page with redirect" status if they had indeed found the redirect?